# inserting select2's multiple select into rails' form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, select2-rails

I am using select2-rails gem and would like to get select2 to work on my multiple select field for `artist_ids` like it does in [this all-js example](http://jsfiddle.net/jeadr/62/). Here is what my erb file looks like now. Addition of the js script did not produce any effect, the form still loads the same way.

```
<%= form_for @event, url: {action: "create"}, html: {class: "nifty_form"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br />
  <%= f.datetime_select :date %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :description, size: "60x12" %><br />
  <%= f.select(
    :venue_id,
    options_from_collection_for_select(Venue.all, "id", "name")
  ) %>
  <%= f.collection_select :artist_ids, Artist.all, :id, :name, {:selected => @event.artist_ids, include_blank: true}, {multiple: true} %>
  <br />
  <%= f.submit "Create" %><br />

    <% content_for :js do %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#event_artist_ids').select2();
    });
    </script>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I followed all the usual procedures for adding select2 as instructed in the docs. Added `//= require select2` line in application.js and `*= require select2` with `*= require select2-bootstrap` to application.scss.

UPDATE:

after Prashant Ravi Darshan suggestion, it looks like select2 has started working, though with bugs. now it's two messy fields for selecting an Artist

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this

```
<%= f.select(:artist_ids, Artist.all.collect {|a| [a.name, a.id]}, {}, id: "event_artist_ids", :multiple => true) %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#event_artist_ids" ).select2();
</script>
```

Comment: hey! that got the select2 to work, though with some hiccups. I added screenshot in OP. any idea what that mess is about?

Comment: you can fix the width issue by giving width:100% to select tag.

Comment: @sivanes
There are three approaches you can follow. I am not 100% sure but try with them.
1- remove html: {class: "nifty_form"} from form_for tag
2 - remove all js and css from application. but contain only below 
application.css
 
*= require_self
*= require bootstrap.min
 *= require select2
 *= require select2-bootstrap

in application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require select2

Comment: Many Thanks @PrashantRaviDarshan. I have used with has_many table in rails 5 and works like a charm. I struggled so much with this. But I'm now using with gem - act_as_taggable + select2 just like this one. However, as the gem has its own functions, I cannot even view the tags. it doesn't allow Tag.all. as you have done in your answer. Pls have a look at my query and you can leave your answer there - .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877283/rails-5-ask-as-taggable-with-select2

Answer (score 3):

It seems that every example of Select2 working on Stackoverflow is through simple_form_for. Some have expressed the sentiment that form_for will not work because select2 does not accept f.select... I spent several hours figuring out how to get mine to work and all of the topics I opened, I don't recall anyone with form_for getting anywhere, when people switched to simple_form_for they succeeded.

Comment: wow, I guess that's good to know. I'm still new to Rails and was trying to stay away from simple form with my first major project, as I heard that it has issues of its own and using the standard Rails form instead helps in understanding how this stuff works.

Comment: on the other hand, here's a working rails + select2 example and no simple_form in the gemfile? https://github.com/jseifer/rails-select2-example/blob/master/Gemfile

Comment: @sivanes I can only speak for what I have seen on stackoverflow