# Select2 is not applied to select element in rails, where do I find the missing link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, select2-rails

Pages that helped me so far:

- https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails
- [Rails 5 ask_as_taggable with select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877283/rails-5-ask-as-taggable-with-select2)

Expected outcome:

- I get select2 to be applied to my select element. From that moment I'll start fixing things myself again.

Actual outcome:

- Select2 is not applied to the select element.

Steps I've taken so far:

1. add it to gem, do bundle install.
2. add `//= require select2` like this

:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap/modal
//= require turbolinks
//= require select2
//= require_tree .
```

---

3. added the require select2 and require select2-bootstrap to application.css

:

```
*= require select2
 *= require select2-bootstrap
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

4. in my `name.html.erb` there is:

:

```
<%= f.label :tag_list, "Topics" %>
<%= f.select(:tag_list, Tag.all.order(:name).collect { |a| a.name }, {}, id: "tag_list1", label:'Tags', :multiple => true)%>
```

I've created a `Tag.rb` (data gets saved to the db):

`class Tag < ApplicationRecord
   validates_presence_of :name
end`

5. now the final step (from what I understand), I apply the functionality to the element (adding the code to `application.js` below the `//= require_tree .`):

   `$( "#dropdown" ).select2({
   theme: "bootstrap"
   });`

changed this to:

`$( "#tag_list1" ).select2({
    theme: "bootstrap"
});`

Console:
`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function`

I solve this with:

```
(function($){
  $(document).on('ready', function(){
      $("#tag_list1").select2({
        theme: "bootstrap",
        tags: true
      });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Expected outcome:

- I get select2 to be applied to my select element.

Actual outcome:

- Select2 is not applied to the select element.

Please advise.

---

**Update 1**
This is the html output:

```
<input name="item[tag_list][]" type="hidden" value="">
<select id="tag_list1" label="Tags" multiple="multiple" name="item[tag_list][]">
  <option value="12">dev tool</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Check if you html follow this kind of structure https://jsfiddle.net/pwzydv67/1/

Comment: @Hackerman added the html snippet to update 1 in the question. I see the change in lay out in the jsfiddle you've shared when I change the id to tag_list1 in the html element.

Comment: @Hackerman if I use your JS/JQuery snippet I get the error mentioned earlier `.select2 is not a function`.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your server after installing the `select2` gem?

Comment: @Trinculo yes I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `DOM`. You should see the following order of loading: jQuery, select2 and then your js files. ( source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42671121/6430382 )

Instead of `ready` add `turbolinks:load`

Make a file called `/assets/javascripts/select2.js`:

```
//= require select2-full

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
  $("#tag_list1").select2({
    theme: "bootstrap",
    tags: true,
    placeholder: "Max 5 topics"
  });
});
```

Expected outcome: you get `select2` added to your element with all functionality.